# NullPointException on child Fragment ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

Im trying to change the background of my `ConstraintLayout` My code:

**fragment_user.xml**

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/profile"
    android:name="com.app.ProfileFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"/>
```

**fragment_profile.xml**

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPopupBackground"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:id="@+id/profile_layout">
```

**UserFragment.kt**

```
private fun showProfile(){
    val fragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.profile)!!
    fragment.view!!.findViewById<ConstraintLayout>(R.id.profile_layout).setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
    profile_layout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
}
```

I actually get a `NullPointException` on `profile_layout`. Any idea why?

Error Logcat:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference
        at com.app.UserFragment.showProfile(UserFragment.kt:114)
        at com.app.UserFragment.onClick(UserFragment.kt:87)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7251)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7228)
        at android.view.View.access$3500(View.java:802)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:27843)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7116)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
```

Comment: Have you assigned it from your layout? `profile_layout = findViewById(R.id.profile_layout)`

Comment: can you post your error logcat

Comment: added logcat @sasikumar

Comment: Yes and I get the same null exception @MetaSnarf I've added the code in my edit

Comment: Where is showProfile called from. onViewCreated()? are you using kotlin synthetics?. move the showProfile to onViewCreated.

Comment: Yes kotlin synthetics. No showProfile() is called in `onClick()`. @Raghunandan

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code

```
 profile_layout.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!, R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
```

with

```
activity?.let{
profile_layout.setBackgroundColor(it.getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark))
}
```

Comment: Requires API 23, I'm running API 21 as a minumum SDK.

Comment: go to app build.gradle change  minSdkVersion to 23

Comment: I do not want to change the minSDK @sasikumar

Answer (score 0):

Please write:

```
activity?.let{ activity -> profile_layout?.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity,R.color.colorPrimaryDark)) 
}
```

Comment: still not changing the background color

Answer (score 0):

Managed to access the parent from it's child instead:

```
val parent = child.parent as ConstraintLayout
        parent.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(activity!!, R.color.colorTransparent))
```

which now works.